# Desenvolver em C# usando Mono Develop Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop

Preciso programar em C# e usar Linux. Li um pouco sobre o Mono Develop, gostaria de saber em que aspecto funcional o Mono fica devendo ou se destaca em relação ao Visual Studio e se existem outras alternativas para desenvolver em C# usando Linux.

Answer (score 1):

O Mono fica devendo em algumas bibliotecas específicas para Windows Forms e aplicações Web.

Agora com o fim do suporte para aplicações Silverligth (Moonligth), o WPF fica um pouco comprometido.

Veja este link com alguns comparativos: https://desenvolvedorinteroperavel.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/executando-aplicaes-net-no-linux/

Comment: Não conheces outra solução?

Comment: @DaviAragao recentemente a Microsoft criou o Visual Studio Code, que promete rodar nativamente em ambientes Windows, Linux e Mac OSX. Mais informações em https://www.visualstudio.com/products/code-vs